# Best way to authorize User against Azure AD Group in SPA (React JS)

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

We want to authorize User against Azure AD group in SPA (React JS); i.e. User allows to access API from SPA if he/she belongs to a Particular group (e.g. testgroup). Found sample code in [Msal.JS](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-javascript-graphapi-v2).

I'm following

- Create UserAgentApplication object
- Call Loginpopup (here graph scope is - "Directory.Read.All")
- Call acquireTokenSilent (get access token to call MS Graph Api)
- Call MS Graph to retrieve all AD Groups where User belong to

  Url to get AD Groups - https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/memberOf
- After receiving the **Ad Groups** (user belong to), validating whether User belong to that AD groups ( here - testgroup)

Please suggest me whether I am going in Right direction or any other options are available.

Thanks for your suggestion.

Regards,

Deb

Comment: If your SPA is running in client browser, then check to authorize based on user's membership in one or more groups should really be in the API in my opinion.. you could still control what to show/hide from SPA but actual authorization being in API would make sense.. Also consider using Application Roles supported by Azure AD applications, as they are meant for a similar purpose. I've seen applications using group claims, application roles or even a combination to make authorization decisions..

Comment: Thanks Rohit, Yes our SPA will run in client browser. As of now we haven't implemented User Authorization in API, will do. But now we want to authorize user against Azure AD group in SPA. Can you please provide me any sample for group claim on SPA ( React JS).

Comment: Yeah you really have to check those in the API. Checking them in the UI is sort of a convenience for users so they don't see options they can't use anyway. If you don't check them in the API, you have a major security vulnerability.

Comment: Thanks @Juunas. For our requirement we will validate (whether user belongs to a AD group) user while logging into the system in SPA, post login User will interact with API from SPA.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using *msal.js*, I used [react-aad-msal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-aad-msal). It is *msal* wrapper library and it went much smoother.
I would try this
https://ahsanshares.wordpress.com/2019/10/19/react-app-consuming-microsoft-graph/